# Create link from php variable

Tags: php, url, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce and I'm trying to create a simple button that links to a supplier's website.  The website url is an attribute within each product but I can't figure out the painfully basic way of using a php value as a url.

At the minute I'm using the following to display the text of an attribute:

```
<?php
$suppliervalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_supplier');

  foreach ( $suppliervalues as $suppliervalue ) {
  echo $suppliervalue->name;
    }
?>
```

All I think I need to do is convert this so that it says:

```
<?php
$suppliervalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_supplier');

  foreach ( $suppliervalues as $suppliervalue ) {
  echo <a href="$suppliervalue->name;">Click here</a>
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax

```
<?php
$suppliervalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_supplier');

foreach ( $suppliervalues as $suppliervalue )
{
    echo '<a href="'.$suppliervalue->name.'">Click here</a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've not quite got the echo syntax correct.

```
<?php
$suppliervalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_supplier');

foreach ( $suppliervalues as $suppliervalue ) {
    echo '<a href="' . $suppliervalue->name . '">Click here</a>';
}
?>
```

Give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

You can create links the following ways:

```
echo '<a href="'.$suppliervalue->name.'">Click here</a>';
```

or

```
echo '<a href="{$suppliervalue->name}">Click here</a>';
```

or

```
$link = '<a href="';
$link.= $suppliervalue->name;
$link.= '">Click here</a>';
echo $link;
```

or

```
$link= sprintf("<a href='%s'>Click here</a>",$suppliervalue->name);
echo $link;
```